# Mef import all types implementing an interface specified at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mef

Can i write a class to use mef to import all types implementing a specific interface and then specify this interface at run time.  (i know i need to tag the implementors with export)

Example usage:

```
IEnumerable<IExcitingClass> excitingClasses = ClassImporter<IExcitingInterface>.ImportAllFrom(specifyDirectory);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container using a DirectoryCatalog, and call `container.GetExportedValues<IExcitingClass>`.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

At run time you could only use string to specify your interface.

```
    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllInheritors(string interfaceName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
        foreach (var part in Container.Catalog.Parts)
        {
            Type type = assembly.GetType(part.ToString());
            if (type != null)
                if (type.GetInterface(interfaceName) != null)
                {
                    yield return part.CreatePart().GetExportedValue(part.ExportDefinitions.First());
                }
        }
    }
```